# How to deal with circular references in Objective-C model relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have a `User` model, and a `Post` model. A `Post` model has one `User`, and a `User` model can have multiple `Post`s.

Now in the `Post` detail controller, I have a `Post` and the corresponding `Post.user`. The user is a strong reference, because if it weren't the user object wouldn't remain in memory. The backend response I get is something like:

```
    response of post/:id
    {
        post fields
        user: {user fields}
    }
```

From the `Post` detail controller, I can also go to the `User` detail controller, where the `User` has an array of `Posts` that are strongly held in an array. I have to have these as strong references, because otherwise they'd not stay in memory.

Now my problem is that the response for the list of `Posts` by a user doesn't have a user field inside the response, so for each `Post` I have to link back to the same user that already has a strong reference to the `Post`.

So my basic problem is that in some cases, I want the relationship from `Post` -> `User` to be `strong`, while in other cases I want it to be `weak`.

For now, I have two properties in my `Post` model, one strong and one weak, and based on the situation, I set the appropriate property.

But is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about which object "owns" the other. Aside from memory management, that's what the `strong` and `weak` keywords indicate. I would say that `User`s own `Post`s, because it would be weird to have thousands of posts that each owned their own users-- but it makes sense to have thousands of users each owning their own posts.

So why not keep a running list of the users you encounter, and each time you find one of their posts you add a strong reference to their corresponding `User` object. Each post would have a weak reference to the user who created it. This won't cause the post to be prematurely freed because as long as you retain the list of users, all the posts contained in it will stay in memory.

Hope this helps!